# Anyway to group a date field without grouping all pivot tables that have the exact same date field?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a worksheet called data.  It has a field called "date" that's date/time.

I'd like to be able to pivot out the daily results and quarterly results in the same workbook.

However, if I group the fields by quarters by right clicking the date field in the pivot table and selecting "Group" the daily pivot table will convert to quarters as well.  This appears to be the case for ANY pivot table that shares the same source data and the same field name.

Is there an easy way around this, or should I calculate a "Quarter" field in the "data" worksheet and pivot based on "Quarter"?

Comment: You could add a column to your data that bundles the Quarters & then you can use the field that you want when/where you want it

Comment: @pnuts - that question is closed. So general stackoverflow question here...should I delete my question or answer my own and mark it answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the simplest way to do this is to:

1) Add a quarter field to the "data" worksheet and pivot off that

OR

2) Create a quarter table (but not a pivot table) that calculates the quarter results by adding the results (from the pivot table) between the start and end date.